# Creating RestTemplate with new RestTemplate vs restTemplateBuilder

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

What is the difference in creating RestTemplate this way

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeout))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
                .build();
```

and this way

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableCookieManagement().build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

????

Comment: To start with, the `restTemplateBuilder` might have additional configuration such as interceptors (distributed tracing and metrics are common).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question about Scope restTemplateBuilder.As mention in Spring Document:

[Scope of restTemplateBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzckj.png)

> To make the scope of any customizations as **narrow** as possible, inject
>   the auto-configured **RestTemplateBuilder** and then call its methods as
>   required. Each method call returns a new **RestTemplateBuilder** instance,
>   so the customizations only affect this use of the builder.

Example:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public HelloController(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    this.restTemplate = builder.build();
}
```

> To make an **application-wide**, additive customization, use a
>   **RestTemplateCustomizer** bean. All such beans are automatically
>   registered with the auto-configured **RestTemplateBuilder** and are
>   applied to any templates that are built with it.

Example

```
static class ProxyCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.example.com");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy) {

            @Override
            public HttpHost determineProxy(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
                    throws HttpException {
                if (target.getHostName().equals("192.168.0.5")) {
                    return null;
                }
                return super.determineProxy(target, request, context);
            }

        }).build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }

}
```

Note: For narrow using **RestTemplateBuilder**. For application-wide using **RestTemplateCustomizer**

Reference link: [Reference link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html)

Additional detail example: [Additional example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder)